# Change default calendar for automatically generated Google Calendar events

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

I'm a big fan of the Google Calendar feature where a calendar event automatically gets generated from certain emails.
I would however like to have some more control of this process, akin to how I can set up filters that sort my email into separate folders or does other actions.

To be precise, now in corona-times, I get quite a lot of  invites to various zoom/teams/etc.. meetings that are job related. I would like that these events show up in my work calendar and not in my private "default" calendar - while preferably leaving other events still in the "default" calendar.

Can this be done, and how?

Comment: Welcome to [webapp.se]. There are no built-in features for this, please send your feedback directly to Google. If you need further help show what you tried, add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]. P.S. You might need to use Google Apps Script  / Google APIs, the first is on-topic here, the second not. There might be already and add-on that does this, if you need a software recommendation consider posting your question on [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score -1):

I can't find a default calendar setting.
But if I have a bunch of updates for a particular calendar, I realized that by unchecking all calendars EXCEPT the calendar you want to default to, it works.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean here. I still want to be able to see my other calendars, i would expect unchecking them makes them invisible. Can you please elaborate?